# File variable are set to null when go back to previous task

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

### The process flow to simulate the issue

1. Task1 with an download element¹ to be showed if there is a file;
2. Task2 with an upload input file element² and an approve or not (approved) variable; **NOTE THAT I CAN DOWNLOAD THE FILE AT THE NEXT TASK (e.g. task03) BUT NOT AT PREVIOUS TASK**
3. approved = false;
4. Task1 show the download element¹ with the file_task2 variable; **HERE THE ISSUE**

¹`<a id="showDownloadFileTask2" cam-file-download="file_task2"></a>`

²input element at embedded formTask2:

```
    <input type="file"
            cam-variable-name="file_task2"
            cam-variable-type="File"/>
```

### Explaining the issue more deeper

I used the console.log from cam-script at embedded form

```
  <script cam-script type="text/form-script">
        $scope.userName = '';
        var variableManager = camForm.variableManager;

        camForm.on('form-loaded', function() {
              try {
                variableManager.fetchVariable('file_task2');
              } 
              catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
              }
        });

       camForm.on('variables-fetched', function() {
          console.log("file = "+variableManager.variableValue('file_task2')); //file = null
          if(processAndGetVariable('file_etp_conformidadeETP') == null) {
              document.getElementById('showDownloadFileTask2').style = "display: none;";
          }
        });
  </script>
```

### How can I access that variable from task1 form ?

Input/Output ?
Create the variable at start process?
What else can I do?
Maybe create the file variable in task2 using camunda modeler ?

Comment: How do you go back to the previous task?

Comment: I set a variable called "approved"; in modeler/xml has a condition to go forward or go to the previous task, its condition depends on the "approved" variable (if false go to previous one else go to next one following the happy path);

Answer (score 0):

I achieve what I was trying to do using the camunda's rest api service. I am doing a request in variables-fetched lifecycle:

```
/engine-rest/task/"+camForm.taskId+"/variables/file_task2/data
```

That way I can get all the variables already declared in the execution proccess.